# Is there an easy way to add Const as much as possible in Flutter?

Tags: performance, flutter, dart

I have read the article here about [Final and Const](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-const). I also saw many example code from flutter team use many **const** as they can (just read the example of [todos list](https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/blob/master/examples/todos/lib/main.dart) from package river_pod), and some article about how **compile-time constant widget** good for performance ([like this](https://crizantlai.medium.com/flutter-performance-analysis-of-const-constructor-d2a72fd8a043)).

Is there any easy way let the IDE plugin/lint add const Widget/Variable as much as it can automatically? Or give some hint like `This Widget/Variable' is better to use with const`.

I checked the [lint package](https://pub.dev/packages/lint) here and read [Effective Dart:Style](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style), but didn't see any information about it.

Thanks for help!

I add some example cases:

```
ListView(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 40), // here
  children: [ ...
    const SizedBox(height: 42), //here
    const Image( //here
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      image: AssetImage('assets/logo.png'),
    )
    ...
```

or even a class

```
Container(
  child: const Toolbar(), //here
...

class Toolbar extends HookWidget {
  const Toolbar({Key key}) : super(key: key); //here
  ...
```

Answer (score 13):

It's actually quite simple. You should open **analysis_options.yaml** and then under linter specify the required rules.

```
...
linter:
  rules:      
    - prefer_const_declarations
```

You can check the rules here: https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried your suggestion and didn't notice there already exist some constant checking in Lint. https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#the-analysis-options-file.   But I still have quesiotns that the example I provided above seems not detected. Are my examples not support for `prefer_const_declarations` checking?

Comment: The thing is that, in the cases you've provided, an analyzer may never be able to know your intention. Value marked with const will be deduplicated during runtime and the analyzer never know if you will use that property. It must be done explicitly by the author.

Comment: That mean, the example I provided should be handle by author by experience? I think the examples I provided are simple cases that analyzer may have a chance to detect. If some trade-off cases that I haven't though off? Or something I misunderstand about using the const keyword?

Comment: Your answer is so closed but not fit my situation. I found the **lint rule** I was looking for is `prefer_const_constructors` and `prefer_const_constructors_in_immutables`. Problem solved! Thanks

Comment: Is there any script to do that automatically?

Answer (score 10):

In addition to linting, you can fix most cases of missing or redundant const automatically by running `dart fix --apply`. Run `dart fix --dry-run` first to see what will change.